# Correlation coefficient from ACF/PRCF as dependent/response variable

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, spatial, ecology

I have multiple, 12-year time-series of species abundance data. I want to model different population properties across spatially and temporally varying predictors.

One of the properties I want to investigate "across space" is density dependence. By the use of the partial rate correlation function (similar to autocorrelation function but correlates $\ln(N_t/N_{t-1})$ instead of $\ln(N)$ I get degree of density dependence at different lags (PRCF[1], PRCF[2], etc.).

I therefore wonder if it is appropriate to use the correlation coefficient from the correlation function at, e.g., lag 1 (PRCF[1]) as dependent variable in my regression model?